# How to access the bpm package of the current workflow from java?

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, business-process-management

To get the companyHome I use this method:

```
public NodeRef getCompanyHome()

    {
        return nodeLocatorService.getNode("companyhome", null, null);
    }
```

the spring confuguration is the following:

```
<bean id="TransformationHandler" class="org.alfresco.transformation.TransformationHandler"          parent="baseJavaDelegate" lazy-init="default" autowire="default" dependency-check="default">
      <property name="nodeService" ref="NodeService" />
      <property name="nodeLocatorService" ref="nodeLocatorService" />
</bean>
```

when I loop throug the children of a NodeRef I see the root folder structure(I'm not shure I name them right in english): data dictionary, guest catalog, users home space, published and so on. But as I run my code in the workflow I need to get files I attached to the workflow. What is the way to do this? I'm interested in the configuring workflow model too because in the [tutorial](http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/workflow/tutorial/tutorial.html) there are few information about the bpm:package and the `bpm:packageItemActionGroup` is the only place where the bpm:package can be found. Is this enough:

```
<type name="scwf:activitiApprovedNotification">
    <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
    <overrides>
        <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
            <default>read_package_item_actions</default>
        </property>
    </overrides>
</type>
```

?
So there are two questions: What is the way to access the content of bpm:package and is the provided above part of workflow model enough for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

The one way to access content of workflow is to write webscript for it.
Here is an example of java backed webscript to access some workflow details:

**workflowdetails.get.json.ftl**

```
<webscript>
   <shortname>Get Workflow Task</shortname>
   <description>Retrieves all the workflow tasks which are in progress</description>
   <url>/workflow/details</url>
   <format default="json"/>
   <authentication>user</authentication>
   <transaction allow="readonly">required</transaction>
   <lifecycle>public_api</lifecycle>
</webscript>
```

**WorkflowActiveTaskDetails.java**

```
package util.workflow;

public class WorkflowActiveTaskDetails extends DeclarativeWebScript {
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public void setServiceRegistry(ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) {
        this.serviceRegistry = serviceRegistry;
    }

    protected Map<String, Object> executeImpl(WebScriptRequest arg0, Status status, Cache cache) {
        WorkflowService workflowService = serviceRegistry.getWorkflowService();
        NodeService nodeService=serviceRegistry.getNodeService();
        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        WorkflowTaskQuery tasksQuery = new WorkflowTaskQuery();
        tasksQuery.setTaskState(WorkflowTaskState.IN_PROGRESS);
        tasksQuery.setActive(true);
        List<WorkflowTask> tasks = workflowService.queryTasks(tasksQuery);

        for(int i=0;i<tasks.size();i++) {
            JSONObject jsondata = new JSONObject();
            Map<QName, Serializable> properties= tasks.get(i).getProperties();
            try {
                Date dueDate=tasks.get(i).getPath().getInstance().getDueDate();
                jsondata.put("duedate", dueDate!=null?dueDate.toString().split(" ")[0]:"");
                jsondata.put("priority",tasks.get(i).getPath().getInstance().getPriority());    jsondata.put("initiator",nodeService.getProperty(tasks.get(i).getPath().getInstance().getInitiator(),ContentModel.PROP_FIRSTNAME));
                jsondata.put("description",properties.get(WorkflowModel.PROP_DESCRIPTION));
                arr.put(jsondata);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        model.put("data", arr);
        return model;
    }
}
```

**workflowdetails.get.json.ftl**

```
{data}
```

**Bean configuration:**

```
<bean id="webscript.util.workflow.WorkflowActiveTaskDetails.get" class="util.workflow.WorkflowActiveTaskDetails" parent="webscript">
    <property name="serviceRegistry" ref="ServiceRegistry" />
</bean>
```

And hit this URL:
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/workflow/details

You will get response like

```
[{"initiator":"test5","description":"Test Workflow","priority":2,"duedate":"2014-03-29"},{"initiator":"test5","description":"Test Workflow2","priority":1,"duedate":"2014-03-31"}]
```